# There is someone or someone is there

Tags: grammar

which sentence is correct and why:

1. Look! There's Chris.
2. look! Chris is there.

can we say in the same way:

> there is Chris at home

so actually I think it's correct, because I'm talking about the presence of Chris at home ( in response of: "is Chris at home or not?"), and I'm not talking about the location of chris (in response of: "where is Chris"), am I right?

Comment: Both are correct and both mean just about the same.

Comment: For number 2, "Chris is over there" is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence emphasises that you have noticed that Chris is nearby.

The second, in its proper form "Look, Chris is over there.", focusses on the location of Chris.

> Look! There's Chris.  I didn't think he was coming today.

> Look! Chris is over there.  I thought he was here.